# Limitar a dos decimales en Jquery. Fallo en toFixed()

Tags: jquery

tengo un codigo JQUERY y no consigo limitar los decimales a dos.

Este es mi codigo.

```
$('.cantidax').change(function()

{
    var precio = $(this).parents('td').prev().find('span.amount');
    var total = $(this).parents('td').next().find('span.amount');
    var valorPrecio = parseFloat(precio.text());
    var valorCantidad = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var PrecioxCantidad = valorPrecio * valorCantidad;
    var totales = parseFloat(total.text(PrecioxCantidad));
    var decimales = parseFloat(totales);

    console.log(typeof(valorPrecio));
    console.log(typeof(valorCantidad));
    console.log(typeof(PrecioxCantidad));
    console.log(typeof(totales));
    console.log(typeof(decimales));


});
```

El codigo html con el que trabaja es este

```
<td class="product-price">
   <span class="amount">{{$producto->precio}} €</span> 
</td>

 <td class="product-quantity">
<div class="quantity buttons_added">

<input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty text cantidax"  value="" min="0" step="1" > 

 <a href="" class="btn btn-warning" >
      <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
</a>
 </div>
 </td>

<td class="product-subtotal">
       <span class="amount"></span> 
</td>
```

He probado a sacar el tipo de cada variable con console.log(typeof())
y en todos los casos el resultado es number, pero si uso toFixed() para delimitar decimales, tal que asi.

```
var decimales = parseFloat(totales).toFixed(2);
```

La variable decimales y la variable totales se convierte a NaN. 
Mostrando los resultados son estos

```
       4503.91 
        14 
         63054.74 
        NaN 
        NaN
```

por lo que el fallo esta en

```
var totales = parseFloat(total.text(PrecioxCantidad));      
var decimales = parseFloat(totales);
```

Pero no consigo verlo ¿Que puede estar fallando?

Answer (score 2):

En la línea:

```
var totales = parseFloat(total.text(PrecioxCantidad));
```

el método `text` no retorna el texto del elemento, sino que el elemento mismo, cuando se le pasan parámetros. Para obtener el valor, esta no debe tener parámetros

Comment: Ya se que el elemento text() retorna el elemento, lo que quiero hacer es que en esa casilla escriba el precio por la cantidad, he probado con el metodo ReplaceWith() pero no funciona con el metodo change(). No obstante estoy abierto a sugerencias. Lo que hace el codigo es que usando un input number al cambiar la cantidad el total cambie, he usado el metodo text por que he visto que era mas apropiado pero no descarto otro mejor